# is it possible to unload the relationship data of sqlalchemy objects once loaded?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am working in a library that needs to read several objects that have a one-to-many relationship with another class. The following code represents a highly simplified version of the code of my library:

```
class Plan(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'plan'
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = Column(String)

  points = relationship('Point')

  def __init__(self,name):
    self.name = name


class Point(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'point'

    id          = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    coordinates = Column(String)
    plan_id     = Column(Integer,ForeignKey('plan.id'))

    def __init__(self, coordinates):
        self.coordinates = coordinates
```

I need to read all the data of the relationship (all the points for the example from above), conduct an operation with all the points, and continue with the next object (an object from the Plan class in the example). Since I cannot load all the data in memory because of the high number of points that each plan has, what I would like to do, is after completing the operation with the points objects related to a plan (which I do not need them after the operation), unload them and continue the process with the next plan. I have tried the following approaches:

```
plan.points = []
```

or

```
for point in plan.points:
  plan.points.remove(point)
```

But each of these approaches stacks an update or delete query  (depending on how the cascade attribute is set in the relationship) that implies a considerably overhead to the process, incrementing by 2 or 3 the total execution time and stacking a potentially harmful SQL operation if the session is committed.

Is there a way for unloading objects without the generation of these UPDATE/DELETE queries and  the increment of the execution time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, your objects are only stored in the `Session` using *weak references*, meaning that you can simply delete your own references to the objects to clear them from memory.

That said, you are free to call [`Session.expunge_all()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.expunge_all) to remove any thing still held by the session. Don't call this if you have changes that need to be committed, issue a [`Session.flush()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.flush) first.

You can expunge individual `Point` objects with the [`Session.expunge()` method](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.expunge) too.

See [Using the Session](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html#id1) for more details.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried it (expunge the involved objects first and then plan.points = []) and it works although I get a warning mentioning that the delete operation will not proceed so I do not know if this is the best method for carrying on this action.